# Android debugging on Bluestack Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluestacks, android-studio-3.2

I tried to log debug message on Android Studio from bluestack emulator.
I can install app and run from Android Studio to Bluesatck but there is no my app name on debuggable process on logcat.

Any help thanks in advance